# Should questions be assigned a skill level?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about a difficulty rating for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions)

When browsing the questions I feel I can answer, I am often frustrated by the fact that there are questions above and below the level I would like to address. I wonder whether people feel we should have a "toddlers pool" for beginners to ask questions, and more "pools" for intermediate and advanced? I see a problem with the definition of the limits of each pool, but I imagine that posting a beginner question in the advanced pool is going to see it thrown out or drowned by the professionals trying to discuss more advanced topics.

This is a dimension I have not seen in the website and although it *could* be solved with tags, it's be better done separately.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions

Comment: So you will use your own skill level to assign a skill level to your question...

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate - I tried to find "pool" and "skill level" but there was nothing. I've up voted the original question. Should I now remove this one? What's the correct behaviour?

Comment: @Bernhard: Leave this question where it is! If you have not found the dupe, it's very likely that someone else will not find it either. But maybe he finds your post.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if it's really about "levels" rather than "specialties"?

Answer (score 1):

You mean instead of `belongs-on-SU` tags you want `belongs-on-toddler`.

Honestly? I hate this idea. Really cluttering the space instead of organizing it. Make up your mind and answer the question or leave it as it is.

Comment: Beginner's questions do not by any means automatically belong on Super User. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26305/why-dont-stack-overflow-users-still-know-how-to-close-questions-appropriately

Comment: @Arjan: You did not understand me correctly. The `belongs-to` tags are annoying. That was my point. I don't think the suggested feature would be any better.

Comment: @John, then indeed I didn't understand correctly!

Comment: I don't mind you saying you hate the idea John, but "Make up your mind" is impolite. The idea stems from the fact that we don't want to trawl through the questions we cannot answer or feel we are not qualified to answer. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Man, if you think "Make up your mind" is impolite we two should never have a face-to-face discussion :]

Answer (score 1):

It is one way to build reputation as an expert to answer beginner's questions you stumble upon. If you only swim in the experts pool, you will never get to see them.

And then there is the odd question that seems to be easy but turns out to be very hard. How would I know as a beginner in the field asking the question?