# Please banish the `expert` tag to the bowels of oblivion

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expert - 18 questions, most of which are "discussiony" topics.  There's no real reason for this tag to exist.

Comment: +1 From me - the tag is useless. I never knew oblivion had bowels. If we threw millions of gallons of laxative into oblivion, what would happen?

Comment: I don't know what'd be produced, but I wouldn't want to parse it with regular expressions.

Comment: I had marked this as `[status-completed]` but I changed my mind.  I removed the existing instances of the tag, but we should probably add it to the blacklist or come up with a synonym for it before this is really complete.  Just for reference, there was only 1 question of the 18 that I retagged to `[expert-systems]`.

Comment: @Bill: Make sure you don't ban it from meta, in case people want to discuss expert sex changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another meta-tag, now banned as a matter of policy.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: Yay. Should we keep our eye out for other meta-tags and report them on the relevant meta site?

Answer (score 3):

Fair enough that "expert" attracts "discussiony" topics, considering that Jon Skeet has a silver "beginner" badge. It's a topsy turvy world out there!

Comment: It's not like he doesn't have enough badges though.  Take it away, he won't miss it!

Comment: @Andy - He'd keep the badge even if we completely eradicate the tag.

Comment: @Andy: When you can snatch the badge away from his hand, it will be time for you to leave.

Comment: @Tim: yeah, but would it hurt to take it? :p

Comment: @Andy: No, you'd probably go unconscious immediately.

Comment: @Andy - Its not Jon you have to worry about, its the pony that is unscrupulous.

Comment: I was wrong, five people actually earned it. Ironic that some of our top experts appear to have earned a silver badge for being a beginner <sigh>:  http://stackoverflow.com/badges/121/beginner

Comment: @Tim: it *is* ironic, considering that non-specialist badges are like labels applied to you (Altruist, Electorate, etc).