# Why is Jon Skeet no longer beginner?

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-badges

Jon Skeet [used to have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59085/please-banish-the-expert-tag-to-the-bowels-of-oblivion/59088#59088) a silver beginner badge, but now [it is no more](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/121/beginner).

Aren't [badges are forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/may-i-lose-a-badge)?

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that meta tags are deader than disco. What I meant was: Skeet earned his beginner badge, and now it's been taken away from him. How do we know that the rest of our badges will be safe from the badge repo man?

Comment: He also doesn't have gold or silver [subjective] tag badges any more. I don't think he'll miss them.

Comment: I think seeing tag badges for meta tags was what finally put Jeff over the edge.

Comment: How many stalkers can one man have? ;)

Comment: what was the requirement for a beginner badge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the [beginner]-tag [is dead](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

**edit** Since Jeff quite emphasized his dislike of meta tags, and since they were indeed useless, he probably decided it was best (and logical) to delete the related badges, too.