# Vote to Prompt Question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

Background:

- [Is it OK for Stack Overflow to treat all questions / answers
  equally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104422/is-it-ok-for-stack-overflow-to-treat-all-questions-answers-equally)
- [How about a difficulty rating for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions)

Based on my daily use of Stack Overflow, the situation Lukas Eder talked about is quite true(at least at some level). As community grows with more and more questions popped daily, many good questions (by good I mean professional or perhaps difficult question which is not easy to answer or even understand) are undervalued (both from voting and viewing perspective), I also agree that we need grade the question level, but I keep my opinion regarding to the way mafutrct suggested.

Good questions usually does not gain much attention and quickly drown in vast number of trivial questions, and hard to evaluate by some simple rigid indices. In addition, I think current badges for question & answer is sufficient and no need to create other badge like "difficult question" to address this issue. What we need is only prompt/advertise these good questions(may be with accepted answer) to community to give them a second chance for viewing, voting and getting more badges.

Two core values of Stack Overflow I like the most is, first, senior user takes the responsibility to drive the community. and second, every decision is made based on voting.

My idea is quite similar with "vote to close" or "vote to delete", perhaps combined with the idea of "Question/Answer of the month", share on Facebook functions and current Question/Answer review strategy, which in short, senior users with proper privilege can vote to prompt a question (should be OK with accepted answer, so answer can get a second chance for valuing too), if voting is greater than 5 for instance, this question get prompted/advertised in the community (or part of community) via Stack Exchange inbox mail,

Some initial thought:

- Privilege is based on tag badge and question tag, e.g. only people gains bronze android badge can vote to prompt question tagged with Android.
- Prompt audience should be restricted within a small amount of senior user, e.g. 10k rep and/or only people who gains bronze android badge.
- Qualified user should have fix number times of vote in a time period, e.g. 5 times per
  month.

My first meta post and hope I didn't throw some stupid idea here.

Comment: Welcome to meta; just be sure you know [voting works differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). :)

Comment: *"As community grows with more and more questions popped daily, many good questions (by good I mean professional or perhaps difficult question which is not easy to answer or even understand) are undervalued (both from voting and viewing perspective)..."* **Can you give us some specific examples?**

Comment: @CodyGray, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561161/how-to-avoid-eclipse-leaks-on-xserver-when-editing-android-xml-files) I read and voted recently regarding to a very specific usage of Eclipse and Android SDK. 1 year old question with only 176 view time, current bountied by another user. if someone can answer it, 350+ rep probably OK, but the answer is still deserve to win a nice or good answer badge. I will see if I can find a more classic question (professional, old with low viewing time and voting).