# Should reputation for questions vs answers depend on site?

Tags: discussion, reputation

There's a Stack Exchange website that provides a lot of value to me, but they are at a situation which, in my opinion, the 5:10 reputation ratio is not fair because providing an answer is much more difficult than asking a good question.

Moreover, specific tags are even less populated by answerers and perhaps getting more reputation would motivate them.
Maybe it would be a good idea to let the website administrators tune the number of reputation that people get rewarded for a question upvote in proportion to bonus for getting an answer upvoted?

Comment: Related: [Shouldn't answering complex questions get more upvotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43360/262755)

Comment: I see a lot of perhapses. Evidence?

Comment: Related: [Is it OK for Stack Exchange to treat all questions / answers equally?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104422/262755)

Comment: Some sites [would actually like questions to be worth more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242712/how-can-se-sites-change-their-reputation-payout) than answers.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree with your statement(s):

1. *Reward points* are not transferable between sites and therefore mean inherently different things on different sites.
2. Stack Exchange already provides a "bonus incentive" system for enticement of answerers - a bounty. Offering up some of your own *points* should be plenty motivation, regardless of the site you're on.