# How do I look for questions at my desired level of experience?

Tags: discussion, question-difficulty

How do I look for questions at my desired experience or difficulty level?

Approaches I'm aware of include:

1. You could look for users who are at your desired experience level (based on their ratio of questions to answers), and see what questions they ask. If you're looking at a specific tag, you could look at the [topusers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/topusers), while if you're looking at an entire Stack Exchange, you can look at the [most active users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top).
2. You could look at the tagging of a question. A question that's tagged [ruby] [strings] is probably a low-experience-level question, while a [idiomatic] tag may indicate they know how to do something, but are looking for a better way to do it.
3. If you're after difficult (or bad) questions, try the unanswered tab.

Ironically, I first [asked about this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/505/how-can-i-look-for-questions-at-my-skill-level) on Japanese Meta because too many questions were beyond my level of experience, but I have the opposite problem on Stack Overflow.

Yes, I've considered going on a flagging spree against questions that aren't just beginner but just bad, but the Ruby community seems to be content with questions I'd rather avoid. They aren't even zealous about duplicates: [Ruby: What's the meaning of [var] << AnotherObj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493577/ruby-whats-the-meaning-of-var-anotherobj) only has 2 close votes!

And before anyone asks, I'm aware that [meta tags for difficulty level are considered harmful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions).

Comment: The easier the question, the more votes it has.  Hard questions have 0 votes.  Awful questions have negative votes.  Its odd, but that's the rule.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ: Do hard questions tend to have fewer views as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  But that's the nature of difficult things.  You do tend to get lucky here, though, and find people who have experience in what you are doing.  And, if not, once you suffer through your problem *you* become that person.

Answer (score 10):

Just wait. Don't go for the ones that have just been posted; the newbie questions often float to the top. It's a bit lazy, but I often let others do the dirty work for me and look at upvoted, unanswered questions. Keep question voting yourself and try to attract interest to the more interesting questions and be part of a virtuous cycle of filtering.

It can be a pain, I agree.

Comment: This way you will overlook good questions that got crappy answers. I would love to say that this scenario is uncommon but unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: @WladimirPalant If a question gets *only* crappy answers then it should remain on the Unanswered list.  Questions are considered Unanswered until they have answers that are either upvoted or accepted.

Comment: @WladimirPalant: Do those bad answers get upvoted?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Sometimes - by other people who didn't bother to read and/or understand the question. For example, a question tagged [tag:firefox-addon] and [tag:javascript]. People watching [tag:javascript] will immediately reply with an answer about same-origin policy. Others upvote this answer. And nobody notices that the question is about add-ons that don't care about same-origin policy.