# Do questions still need to show code in the question? (if it's relevant)

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

This is a little extension of the question here [Are code questions without an attempt now on topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic).

I've only just noticed the new close reasons and the removal of the

> describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it
>   reason.....yada yada

Close reason.

I do understand that this close reason was being abused and I actually agree that that abuse needed to be stopped. But given that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it is still off topic according to the FAQ. What should be the close reason now for these questions?

Nothing, to my mind, seems to fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those questions that don't include valid code to reproduce the problem, "unclear what you're asking" is a good close reason.

As always, it's often beneficial to also leave a comment describing what the OP can specifically do to improve the question.

Comment: This does feel like a clear message with specific advice has been replaced by a vague one however

Comment: Does the FAQ need updating then?

Comment: I've *very nervously* updated the answer in the FAQ question.

Comment: We shouldn't *have* to leave a comment in addition to the close reason.  We'd be better off using the freeform close option than to use "unclear what you're asking".