# What have I done wrong? Flamed for asking a question?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, specific-question, moderation

Just look at what happened here, very simple question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386037/how-can-i-take-take-text-and-display-it-in-an-image-in-asp-net-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment32254569_21386037

Comment: That comment isn't flaming you at all.  It seems to be entirely constructive.  I see no inappropriate comments at all on that question.

Comment: its not the comments its flagged for not asked question correctly, aka they use "off topic" by the god mods over and over

Comment: Not flamed, but your question was closed. Nobody was rude. Requests for a library are offtopic. And downvotes on meta express disagreement. People are saying that you have misinterpreted the situation.

Comment: they I stay misinterpreted the situation until answered.  either they don't know. (most google examples said this might not work) so I did my homework.  even into the comments they all agree what im looking for and it should not have been closed

Comment: I don't see the request for a tool or library, so I disagree with the specific close reason selected.  But overall the question is not great.  Questions that just say "I want to do Foo, how do I do it" tend not to be received well by the community, and attract downvotes.

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Your question, both the one linked there and particularly here, are of exceedingly low quality.  The downvotes are very much deserved in my eyes for the lack of effort they demonstrate.  Nobody has flamed you; the only inappropriate language I see used anywhere is coming from you.  We expect content provided on this site to be of high quality.  All questions are not acceptable, all answers are not acceptable.  If you're unwilling to live up to the quality standards...there's the door.

Comment: yup agree with @jball, even though this guy is asking about drawing on winforms, I asked about drawing on a image file(my question is "more" correct") this is what I was looking for.  what a horrible experience here

Comment: I also agree with @jball here. People are just overwhelmed by the amount of really bad questions that they auto downvote and close everything, even if just innocent question that might be somewhat trivial and asked before. No flames, just bad decisions in my opinion.

Comment: can somebody reword, such a simple question?

Comment: Top tip: don't say stuff like *"You down voters should be ashamed, as well as "off topic" god mods perfect understandable example"*. Mistakes are made. And you'll have to rely on the exact same community to correct those mistakes. Annoying those who have to do that makes them less inclined to respond positively. No matter how annoyed or upset you are, keep it cool.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way.](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: well all my points where justified some "mod" fixed everything. But im not a new programmer, although, this is a simple question because its in a different field that I do not normally work in.  You can build cars for life, but never work on interior ever.

Comment: I googled the question all different ways and nothing was working.  Eventually I had to get my answer on google other than here because of what happened.  This was just a bad day to ask a question on Monday because a question asked long ago, no different than mine, (accept his was incorrect saying WinForms when the answer was in html), was the answer in that thread and what I needed. I thank what ever admin who looked up me or my history and adjusted my reputation a ton

Comment: oddly @jball's comments here have been removed.  He was adding to the conversation fairly

Comment: this is an old question, all of a sudden a moderator goes through all my questions and puts them off topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858344/active-directory-same-domain-but-can-i-get-dns-to-reslove-different-domain-name

Answer (score 20):

The down votes and the close votes really reflect 2 different issues.

### First the close votes.

Your post attracted 5 close votes but the decision was split between at least 3 different reasons as the close reason only had 2 voters that selected it:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

There was also at least 1 possible duplicate close vote (plus one close as a duplicate flag on a different question).  Only a mod can tell us the specific close reasons selected, but I'd guess there was at least 1 (or maybe 2) votes to close as "unclear what you are asking" or "too broad".

In the end, a majority of close voters did not select the specific close reason, but it was only a plurality.  Unfortunately, due to the way close vote conflicts are resolved, this was the reason it was selected.

I have a feeling this closure was a direct result of the community is still adapting to the [removal of a specific close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic) that would have likely been the close reason if it still existed.  Sometimes the community is searching for a close reason to what they see as a bad question, and you end up with a good mix of different close reasons.

Bad close decisions happen all the time.  There's really no way to avoid them, but the community is self correcting, and bad closures can easily be reversed, although sometimes they need a little help via editing.  In this case, despite your unconstructive attitude, the process worked as designed, and the question was reopened and it was reclosed as a duplicate, like it should have been originally.

---

### Now for the downvotes.

I don't see a problem with the downvotes.  Without the fluff, your question boils down to "I have to create an image with text, how do I do it" without evidence of any effort or research of your own.  The community has decided that questions like that are not of good quality and tend to downvote them.  Had you included some effort on your own, you probably could have avoided most of the initial downvotes.

Some of the more recent downvotes were due something we have dubbed the *Meta Effect*.  Simply speaking, the extra attention you have drawn to your post by asking this question has drawn extra eyes on your post which resulted in more downvotes.  I can't say for certain, but some of those extra downvotes might have been due to your attitude here.  As [Bart has mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217662/what-have-i-done-wrong-flamed-for-asking-a-question/217666#comment705525_217662), trying to get help by insulting the community usually does not usually end up going in your favor.

Stack Overflow is not a site for everyone.  We don't accept any programming question under the sun.  A large part of the reason of the popularity of the site is the quality of the questions and the answers, and the community is very aggressive in moderating posts to maintain that quality.  If you want to ask someone to write your code for you, or do your research for you, then this might not be the community for you.

Comment: It would also be fair to point out that with the downvotes in the past 47 min is the meta effect... that asking people to look at one's question, people do so, and do so with a more critical eye.

Comment: @MichaelT agreed, I originally mentioned it but removed it as I didn't want to confuse the situation too much.  Frankly, I think the OP's attitude here had a large bit to do with the recent downvotes as well, but in the end, the question was not good and the original downvotes were justified in my opinion