# What is the "meta effect"?

Tags: discussion, meta, terminology

I often hear the term ***"meta effect"*** on many meta SE sites. What is the meta effect? I have Googled it but can't find anything about it on any meta site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217662/what-have-i-done-wrong-flamed-for-asking-a-question/217666#217666

Comment: @random I dont understand... how does it answers my question. please explain. :)

Comment: @SMR: if you read the answer he linked thoroughly, the definition is right there.  Ctrl+F if necessary.

Comment: Where have you seen it written with a hyphen?

Comment: I'm tempted to show you by downvoting all your posts... ;-)  (serial voting will be reversed though and I might be banned/punished)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773

Comment: The Googler becomes the [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22meta%20effect%22%20site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It is the effect of mentioning a post from another site on a meta-site. This draws more attention to the post you link from the meta-site's audience, resulting in more views than you'd get from the host site's audience alone, and often more votes. Whether those votes are up or down will depend on the quality of the post, of course...but either way, that's the "meta effect".

Comment: Sometimes it's more extreme and more than just votes. I remember a case where a user complained about unjustified downvotes or something like that and turned out he's a spammer. As expected, his remaining posts were flagged and nuked.

Comment: the meta effect brought me up here :)

Comment: Here, have an upvote. I think it's the meta-meta-meta effect, if you land here whilst looking for references for the meta effect so that you can talk about the meta effect.

Comment: A recent example on Music: Practice and Theory had a user do a similar thing, posting a bunch of comments asking for downvote clarification and going to Meta. User then asked about the 40-vote/day limit, and an eagle-eyed user realised that asking about that on day one of their account was suspicious, and the user was unmasked as a proxy for a suspended account. Basically the Meta effect.