# Should Stack Overflow questions always include a SSCCE?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, close-reasons

I see many questions closed with the following, when code samples are not required and irrelevant:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe
>   the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the
>   question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

For example, [Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setControlKeepAliveTimeout(J)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988433/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-setcontrolke).

Does that mean that every question should include a code sample and describe the specific problem in detail?

Comment: Logically speaking, if code samples were not required and irrelevant, then the question was not about "problems with code you've written"—so the close reason was wrong to begin with.

Comment: Sometimes people use their votes badly, this is the problem with humans. Although the quoted example does need some code to reproduce it. Doesn't mean all question do, but that one does

Answer (score 8):

> Does that mean that every question should include a code sample and describe specific problem in detail?

If your question involves asking why your program doesn't work properly, we do require that you provide a code sample that reproduces the problem and is small enough to fit comfortably in a question, and that you describe exactly what the problem is.

Note that "It doesn't work" is not a problem description.