# The close dialog says there are two off-topic votes, but none of the off-topic reasons have votes next to them

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

I've found strange behavior when closing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997031/how-to-check-fake-traffic-hits) - I definitely see that there are 3 closing votes and 2 of them are at "Off-topic" section:
[image]

-but there are no explanations on section itself:
[image]

-while, normally, it's expected that it will appear. In custom comments section there are also no closing-votes displayed.

Perhaps it's just my browser (which is FF 26 x64 under Win) - so marking this as a "possible bug". Thank you for your attention.

Comment: wontfix sounds more appropriate than bydesign... Was there really a conscious design decision to just hide the votes? :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two of the specific offtopic reasons, namely the "minimal understanding" and the "describe specific problem" close reasons were removed.  (See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215546/186381) for details.)  There are still close votes for those reasons, you just can't see them.

This is the intended behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Now all is clear.