# Why are there still 100K+ closes in the close review queue after two close reasons were removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Shouldn't all of the flags and close votes for the recently-removed close reasons have been deleted?

Answer (score 12):

These vote reasons were <strike>removed</strike> deactivated, but the close votes that were posted with those reasons weren't deleted. Same for the close flags that were cast using them.

You can even still indirectly "see" these old votes: [The close dialog says there are two off-topic votes, but none of the off-topic reasons have votes next to them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215556/closing-vote-possible-bug)

Comment: I think it would help to indicate that the close reasons were not *removed*, but *deactivated*. They still exist, you just can't use them anymore.