# How should I respond to criticism from moderating users on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, new-users

I would like to find out whether there is any recourse when a someone with the power to delete or change questions behaves in a way that seems unreasonable.

I asked this question:
[Why doesn't my Qt application present a GUI when executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065353/qt-newbie-mac-i-was-given-code-and-a-pro-file-to-compile-a-gui-compiles-but?noredirect=1#comment31678654_21065353)

I'm a newbie as far as QT and submitted a question asking for help in understanding why I can't run an executable that I generated using QT.  From past experience, I know that there may be commands that should be added in a .pro file to make a program work in specific circumstances.  I was hoping someone might be able to look at my .pro file and suggest a  solution.  I felt I was polite and clear.

A person who seems to be a moderator immediately jumped on the question and down-voted it.  He said that he didn't see a problem, so the question would be closed.  I politely asked him to leave it up because another user had started engaging with me.  He then replied with a cryptic and rather obnoxious comment about staying on topic.

At this point, I expect he will have the post deleted and I will simply go to another forum to get help elsewhere.

I understand that this is a pretty minor issue in the general scheme of things.  I understand that questions need to meet a certain standard.  I'm OK with being told that there is a problem with a question.  But too often, certain members seem to be on a mission to assert their power and be jerks--deleting or over-editing questions to the point that they don't make sense.  I have seen this happen with other users and mostly it affects newbies--who are then scared away from the site.

When this happens, is there any way of getting a second opinion from a second moderator, to keep the power-hungry people in check and polite and have questions reinstated?

Comment: If you see a username with a diamond, that's a moderator. Others are high rep users.

Comment: Thanks.  Do the high-rep users have the ability to modify posts?  By the way, I see that the guy who has been a pain as far as my question has edited his posts to sound less obnoxious.

Comment: The user who you talked with wasn't a moderator, rather he was a user who can vote to close questions. Keep in mind 5 people have to vote-to-close a question, not just one (except if it's a diamond moderator).

Comment: @hichris123. Thanks for the explanation.  I'm OK with that.  If five people think my questions are a waste of time and off-topic, then I would accept their decision.  I was irritated that one person might have the ability to derail things.

Comment: Calling a moderator "power-hungry" is as dumb as calling a janitor "power-hungry" because he gets to clean up garbage in the schoolyard

Comment: Sorry, but casting a close vote (or any other kind of vote) on a question at any of the StackExchange sites is not being "Power-Mad". It's part of the basic, designed functionality of the sites. So is user moderation, by the users who have earned the privileges to do so. You might want to revisit the About and Help Center pages at SO, if you're unclear about how the site works.

Comment: @Pëkka, I think you're taking this too personally.  I'm actually a moderator myself at a forum.  I know how much work it can be.  I have been very careful, if you read my post again, to clarify that I'm aware my questions might not always be clear or worth posting or whatever.  Forums don't last once people stop being respectful.  Users are scared away.  My question is reasonable.  As a moderator or a frequent site-user or whatever you are, your goal should be to keep the site respectful and to prevent people from piling on new users.

Comment: *"Do the high-rep users have the ability to modify posts?"* -- please read [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) And while in that Help Center, there's more interesting things there, like [Help Center > Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation).

Comment: @Ant I'm not a moderator so I have no personal stake in the discussion, but wouldn't you agree that calling people doing their job "power-hungry" is a pretty bad way to start a conversation? Moderators are selected with the greatest care, after having built a track record of being a reasonable and nice influence

Comment: @KenWhite, as I have said, I am now clear that one person doesn't have the power to derail things.  I've said that a few times now.  When that person first responded to my question, it certainly seemed like he was trying to.  I have seen responses to other people's questions take a nasty turn.  I think it is reasonable to inquire as to the policy on this kind of behavior.

Comment: Well, elected moderators *do* have the power to unanimously close or delete questions. If you have a specific allegation of misuse of that power, Meta is the right place to post it.

Comment: @Ant: There was no "kind of behavior", other than acting within the designed functionality of the site, which was exactly the point I was making. :-)

Comment: @Pëkka. Well, do you do seem to have some stake in this discussion.  I see I have hit quite a nerve here!  I think that calling someone "power-hungry" is appropriate when he/she seems to make it their mission to get a polite, reasonable question shut down.  I wonder if you saw his original language before he edited it? I am generally VERY open to hearing criticism of my work and questions, but this person crossed a line.  And I have seen on other people's questions that when someone does that, the discussion can quickly turn mean.  It is a pity when that happens.

Comment: @KenWhite, either I'm far too sensitive or you didn't see his original comments before they were edited.  Please try to entertain the possibility that the non-forum-insider might have a valid point!  I have to leave for the day, but thank you all for engaging.

Comment: @Ant: You're right. I only saw your comments back to him, and your original post here (which is the one I posted my first comment on, before it was edited) when *you* came here name-calling ("Power-mad moderator" was the phrase in the title, wasn't it?). :-)

Comment: @Ant I don't disagree people on SO are sometimes out of line and that sucks, but you could have used a more neutral choice of words.

Comment: @KenWhite, yes, I freely admit I called him "power hungry."  I still do!  And I'm pretty sure that you'd react the same way in the same situation.  Unfortunately, we can't see his comments anymore.  You seem to have a lot of interest in schooling me.  That's your right.  It is a pity that you can't step outside your forum insidership for a little and consider that this kind of thing may not be great for the forum.  Not everyone is an old, stubborn fart like me.  Many users simply give up when confronted with obnoxious responses.  Anyway, really do have to leave now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ant fighting obnoxious responses is an ongoing issue that the entire community is spending a gigantic amount of effort on. See e.g. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/ unfortunately, there is no silver bullet.

Comment: The comment you described as cryptic and obnoxious, was it *This question was caused by a problem that can't be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*?

Comment: I was wondering why your question was at `-6` because I was impressed that you would come to *meta* and ask how to respond to criticism.  Most people never ask how to improve, so I think that's great and gave the question an upvote. So, I checked the revisions.  Shog9 wrote that question title, not you. Your question title probably got some people defensive and they downvoted it.  Just FYI.  I see now it's at `-3` so maybe some other people agreed with me.

Comment: @KevinPanko: I personally believe that the issue for some people with the question has been that there is no sign of that the OP may have done something wrong. I see many "help-providing-hungry" people asking for SSCCE for being able to help, but the reply in the OP's case was outstanding for such a request in my experience. I will try to refrain from commenting more because I may be too biased. :-)

Comment: Everybody participating has some good points.  Upvotes to all!

Comment: @KevinPanko, I forget what my original title was, but I don't think it was loaded or obnoxious.  I feel like I usually do a good job at responding to criticism.  I have no problem with admitting my limitations.  In this case, however, my question started off as specifically being about how to deal with a more powerful user who seems to have a bee in his/her bonnet.  I see that many people here have become defensive.  As I've said, I understand that questions from me/others may not always be clear or smart or whatever.  But how to avoid a question being derailed is a valid question.

Comment: @bfavaretto. Actually, no. That was not what he wrote that was a problem. And it wasn't just one comment that he wrote. As I have now said multiple times, the poster edited his comments. It's clear that you can't step outside your clubhouse for long enough to consider that I may have a valid question here.  How to stop a person who has power in the forum from derailing and dumping on OK questions. As I have said, I now understand that five people are required to close a question. But that you and many forum insiders have been so quick to leap to this guy's defense is a pity for non-insiders.

Comment: Ant - consider the possibility that we *have* stepped out of our clubhouse, and recognize that there are occasionally run-ins with less than diplomatic users, and that sucks, and it may drive away some people, and that's too bad, but there isn't a magic switch we can turn to make that go away and the issue has been discussed in hundreds, if not thousands of Meta posts and a lot has been done to address it. (cont'd)

Comment: The user edited their comments; had they not done that, and the comments were really as obnoxious as you say, a moderator would have removed them over time. It was clarified that the user isn't a moderator with any special powers (of whom polite conduct is required even more than from anyone else), but simply a normal user with the same voting rights as tens of thousands of others. It was reinforced that politeness is required here at all times, and you were given hints on what to do if this happens ever again (flag for moderator attention). If that isn't good enough, what is?

Comment: @Ant I wouldn't judge others so fast if I were you. I just asked about that comment because [it's a new canned comment created two days ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215546/167534), and I thought your feedback could add to the discussion, had it been about that specific comment.

Comment: @bfavaretto. Sorry, I didn't realize that.  You and Pekka are right that I should not judge everyone as being one of the old boys!  I do need to avoid being a jerk myself at this point.

Comment: @Pëkka. I do realize how difficult it is to deal with jerks at forums.  And I am happy at this point with the advice I have received here about how to view/act on this kind of thing in future.  You in particular have been very even-handed.  Usually I wouldn't even bother caring about an obnoxious post in a forum. Don't know what this one got my goat.  Maybe because the guy won't go away?  Anyway, I am over it and I appreciate your help.  Signing off for the evening.

Comment: Ant - that sounds great, much appreciated. Thanks for coming to Meta instead of just leaving the place for good - if there's ever another problem that can't be resolved, please be back. Emotions can run high for everyone involved, but there's usually an amicable resolution. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto: fwiw, there was not much content change, and it was even done before the OP's reply came out. I was fixing some English issues in my post as a non-native speaker. It has not changed the  intended meaning, at least not intentionally anyhow. The comment was technical and to the point unlike the personal replies. At this point, I am not sure why this is being rolled on.

Comment: *"I forget what my original title was"* -- you can always click text such as [edited 4 hours ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/215808/revisions) to see that, or  replace the `revisions` part in that URL with `timeline` [to see some other details](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/215808/timeline).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stack Overflow (and the other sites in the Stack Exchange family) are community moderated.

Regular members of the community [earn the privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to help moderate the site so we don't need so many people with diamonds.  When you get 10's of thousands of questions per week, you need the community to help.

Individual users who have at least 2000 reputation can edit questions, and users with at least 3000 reputation can vote to close questions.

However, the post you reference was neither closed nor edited.  It does have 1 close vote, but that doesn't mean anything until it gets 5 close votes, so the "editing" you are referencing is likely comment editing or deletion.  It could have been someone cleaning up their own comments, or if they were offensive, they might have been deleted by the community.

Individual users can edit their own comments within 5 minutes of posting, and can delete their own comments.  The editing is to help fix typos, and the deletion of comments is also helpful in clearing up posts.  Other users can flag comments that they find rude or offensive or otherwise unconstructive.  It is all the ways we help keep the site clean.

If you see a comment that you do not think is constructive, you can [flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) it.  If enough other users flag the same comment, it will be deleted, but also a moderator (the guys and gals with the diamonds) can also delete it.

In the end, the comments should be for clarifying the post and not much else.  It is not for long discussions about the topic at hand.  If you have a post that is attracting a lot of comments, you should pay attention to what those users are trying to say.  Some of them might be harsh and some might be a bit more gentle, but more often than not, they usually have something constructive to offer.  You can then take the advise to help edit your post to make it more constructive and useful, and to help get the answers you seek.

If you ever see a comment chain on a question getting out of wack, either too long or off-topic, you can flag for a moderators to clean up the comments, and possibly move the discussion about the question to meta (sort of like you did here).  the meta discussion should be reserved for discussion the post itself, whether it is on or off-topic and how to fix it, not to discuss the content.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  As I said above, I agree that if a question gets five different "close" votes, then it seems reasonable that it should be deleted.  I would be fine with that.  The guy did edit his posts (which is a good thing--he clearly realized he had overstepped).  I am usually a lurker at stackoverflow (i.e., I look up previously answered questions) and I do think there can be some unpleasant mob-type behavior sometimes.  People are generally great and generous with their time, but some answerers do seem to get away with some awful responses.

Comment: @Ant closing <> deleting.  They are different.  Closing just means "we don't think this question fits the site, but you have an opportunity to fix it up".  Deleting removes the post from view.

Comment: @Ant: you are still confusing closure with deletion.

Answer (score 23):

<sub>(I have no knowledge of [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065353/qt-newbie-mac-i-was-given-code-and-a-pro-file-to-compile-a-gui-compiles-but?noredirect=1)'s topic, so please take no offence if my assessment of your situation is incorrect)</sub>

To me, the core of your question looks like this:

> 1. I have code and a .pro file
> 2. I tried to use the code and .pro file.
> 3. The code is big and messy, so I'm not going to show it.
> 4. Here  is my .pro file: ........
> 5. It compiles but does not run as expected.

Then, someone said that your .pro file looks fine, and requested a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

To which you replied:

> I'm sorry, but the code is huge and old. It is not possible to provide an example that would make sense.

Then, you received the following response:

> @Ant: I am afraid this question will be closed soon, then. There is nothing fundamentally wrong in the project that I can personally tell.

You seem to be focusing on the first sentence, and ignoring the second sentence, which is actually the most important part of the comment. Since this user has lots of reputation in your question's topic, I'll assume that his assessment of your `.pro` file is correct. Then, what remains of your question is basically this:

1. I have code <sup><sup>and a .pro file</sup></sup>
2. I tried to use the code <sup><sup>and .pro file.</sup></sup>
3. The code is big and messy, so I'm not going to show it.
4. <sup><sup>Here is my .pro file: ........</sup></sup>
5. It compiles but does not run as expected.

The **problem** with this question is that others cannot even reproduce your problem, because you're witholding crucial information that's needed for verifying the problem. If you show an equivalent (reduced) code sample, then the experienced ones could step through the whole process, and perhaps spot a silly mistake that you'd never think of.

Answer (score 19):

TL;DR: I am not "power-mad", just a community member as everyone else is here.

Long explanation: I gave a reason for my downvote and close vote in order to get some improvement to the question, because otherwise people cannot help, including me. As I explained over there in the comment, five people would need to cast a close vote for the closure to happen. Also, it is worth noting that closure is not the same as deletion.

I mentioned to the OP that the pasted files are OK, and it should work by design. I have worked with the technology in question for years. I also tried to verify the problem locally.

Instead of merely downvoting and casting a close vote without any feedback for improvement, I wrote to the OP that it would be better to get a self-contained example. That way I can get into a position to help the OP, which I would really like. That is why we are around here, including me, right? :)

I thought the feedback would appreciated, as usually people ask for downvote reasons, et al.

There was no radical content change in my comment. It is very likely the OP did not update the page in the meantime, but I did not change the content significantly. I can probably still quote myself fom memory if needed, but I will skip it, as the discussion seems to have been removed over there.

Having that said this, if someone feels a comment is non-constructive like that, it is always possible to flag it (with over 15 reputation, which the OP seems to have).

Answer (score 11):

I've taken the liberty of editing the title here to reflect a question.

#### First: STAY CALM

The world is full of unhelpful jackasses. Ignore them. Flag particularly unhelpful comments as "not constructive".

#### Second: Do your homework

An awful lot of questions can be answered - or at least *asked* more effectively - by spending a bit of time with Google first. Don't worry if you don't understand everything you find - keep notes, and make use of them when asking or revising your question; letting folks know what you know and what you don't can be invaluable in avoiding unhelpful criticism and obtaining a useful answer.

#### Always: Respond to requests for information or clarification

Sometimes, for all your best efforts, it is not possible for us to answer a question because key information is missing. If someone asks for additional information, do your best to provide it by editing your question.

Comment: "The world is full of unhelpful jackasses" Exhibit A --->

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, relax, drink some water.

You should understand that "off topic" is not the same as "waste of time", and sometimes not even "bad", so don't take it as an insult. It either means that the question should go on another site in the Stack Exchange Network (which IMHO is a legitimate feedback, no one expects a new user to know the exact differences, even seasoned ones may have trouble deciding at times), or otherwise is not considered a good question for Stack Overflow.

To avoid ambiguity in what is considered "good", there are quite elaborate guidelines, but they can all be summarized as "the question and any answer it attracts can not contribute others who will find it in the future". Keep in mind that this is a Q&A site, so you need to include enough information for the answers to be relevant and meaningful (including enough relevant code), reproducible, and otherwise professional.

The user who downvoted and closevoted you (which is not enough to close your question as psubsee2003 explained), is just trying to tell you that this question is missing some crucial information. He's trying to help you (and help the community at the same time). Closing questions that aren't useful due to a missing data is important - otherwise we'll all drown in junk questions that no one can use (I'm not saying yours is one of these, only five members are enough to decide that; so far there's only one.)

Comment: unfortunately, I have seen your post just as I am having to leave the office for the day.  I do understand you.  If you'd seen the guy's original comments, I think you might understand a little better why I asked this question!  I am relaxed now because I understand that one person can't derail things.  Anyway, thank you and good day.

Comment: @Ant Best thing here would be to forget about the guy's comments. We all have had a bad day every now and then (or at least I know I have), and have posted a bitchy comment (or two). No reason to let a few comments spoil your SO experience, just move on.

Answer (score -2):

Many a times I found a question is useful and down-voted. People with huge reputation tends to defy other peoples requirements without a research effort. Research effort has been mentioned in a rule for the site. They should remember not only the stackoverflow members are only watching the site for instant help. People those who are not members and web searchers may come across the same problem in future and this will misguide them, leaving a bad impression on the site. Useful questions/answers are sometimes down-voted, deleted and discouraged but the question/answer with no or little help are encouraged. Very easy to shade the true answer and misguide people. How would take this hypocritical attitude?