# What is guideline on use of outdated close reasons?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I read questions the following two questions but still unclear about Close Votes queue on old questions.

[What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)

and

[Should I vote to close old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194116/should-i-vote-to-close-old-questions)

I have stumble unto old questions that have `lack of minimal understand` as reason to close. I understand that it has been removed as described in the following question:
[Is "lack of minimal understanding" an off-topic reason or not, now? Mixed messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217893/is-lack-of-minimal-understanding-an-off-topic-reason-or-not-now-mixed-messag)

What I'm not sure on is: If question still fails to meet current criteria can I mark it with obsolete close reasons or need to choose current valid reason?

Example of question:

[Query with Join condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019800/query-with-join-condition)

Comment: Do you have a specific question in mind that prompted your question about it here?

Comment: @JasonC I added example

Comment: I noticed you voted as "typographical error"; that seems valid. If you disagree with an old close reason and the flag is old and question is not closed yet, you can simply not vote to close - if it truly should remain open, it will. Conversely, if you see an old closed question where the close reason is not valid (and a new close reason doesn't apply) you can vote to reopen - if it truly should be reopened, it will be. If you *strongly* disagree you can give it a custom flag, but questions that are likely to be closed for the new reasons anyways aren't really worth touching.

Comment: Point being: Use valid close reasons, use them only if they apply, vote as per current rules. The rest will generally take care of working itself out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose a current valid close reason.  Obsolete close reasons have justifications for their removal, and they should no longer be used.

"Lack of Minimal Understanding" was not a bad close reason, but people were constantly co-opting it for "lack of minimal effort," which was never a valid close reason.