# Should I tell the OP to un-accept my answer and post a new one?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, accepted-answer

I gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21837102/608157) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21791310/608157) that didn't directly answer the OPs question due to missing details (of all the places where the OP was calling some code). However, my comments helped the OP track down and solve the problem so the OP up voted and accepted by answer saying:

> David – I'll give you credit for the answer. It was actually the beginTime follow-up that lead to the actual solution I needed. Thank you!

I wanted to respond and ask the OP to post the final solution and accept that instead but I wasn't sure if this was the best way. Then I remembered that I recently asked [how to get more involved in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221047/184424), so I decided to ask what you think.

Should I ask the OP to un-accept my answer and post the actual solution in a new answer?

This is the response that I had in mind for the OP:

> @Axeva I can take the upvote for being "useful" (as the tooltip says) but my answer wasn't the solution. You can post the final solution yourself and accept it. In case someone else has the same or a very similar problem it might help them more than reading through all the comments on this answer.

Comment: Seems fair enough.

Comment: As a result of the comments on your answer do you now know enough to provide the actual solution yourself?  Can you simply edit your answer to include some of the details that were missing before?  If the answer did 70% of the work it's likely best to just edit in the extra 30% than to have a second answer posting the extra 30%.  After all, the ideological design of comments is to help people determine how to best edit the posts they are commenting on so that the comments can eventually be deleted.

Comment: @Servy I told the OP to "consider using [...]" and the OP said it "lead to the actual solution". I could edit my question, refer to the comment and include a general example but I wouldn't know if that was the solution to the OP (though neither would anyone else who stumbled upon the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark this question as closed: I decided to ask the OP to post a new answer. No one had posted an answer to this question so this is my own answer.