# Closure for questions asking for code

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, close-dialog

It seems I've fallen out of touch with closure options for "*give me the codez*" style questions; however, from the close dialog under *off-topic because...* I recall there being options such as:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results.

Then there was:

> Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem
>   being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and
>   how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Also:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe
>   the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See
>   SSCCE.org for guidance.

Is there new sentiment within the community regarding closing these questions; or, what appropriate closure action should be taken?

Questions without code, failing to isolate an example fit well within:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more
>   detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

However, I'm asking for best practice responding to questions that read like a specification document listing requirements or "*I'm new to programming*" questions with wide scope such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738632/click-on-specific-links-on-a-webpage-with-javascript), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923497/windows-batch-search-and-copy-files-to-flash-drive#21923497), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681592/adding-canvas-within-canvas-but-as-a-separate-thread).

Comment: That led me to: *[Improving “demonstrate a minimal understanding” close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason)*, which is pretty close to what I was looking for.

Comment: I've got a canned comment I've started leaving to accompany my "too broad" close votes for the "I don't have any idea what I'm doing" people: "If you're just starting out, asking questions on Stack Overflow is not the place you need to be. You should find a good book or a series of online tutorials. Have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660). The Big Nerd Ranch books are excellent, and lots of people like the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. Good luck!" It's been getting a reasonably good response; you're welcome to fork it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it gets a close vote, when deserved, it really doesn't matter which option you choose. I have noticed they have changed, as well. I can't give you the reason for that or why/when they do but, as I said, the reason isn't important in closing the question.

However, the reason is important for the user to understand why and to know how to use the site appropriately. All of the above seem to fit fine for this type of question, including the latest, "lacks sufficient information...".

You also always have the ability to enter a custom message if you don't feel any of the current options fit.

"Is there new sentiment within the community regarding closing these questions", nope. These should still be closed if they are just asking for the "codez" and show no effort.

Personally, for all of them that you linked to, I would close due to "insufficient information" then possibly leave a comment instructing them on providing their attempts and to show research effort.