# Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I noticed we no longer have the option to close for minimal understanding.
However, in the help center it is still mentioned:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question
>   checklist

Can we still use this as a close reason within the "other" close reason. Some questions really have no understanding whatsoever.

Comment: And in these cases it doesn't make sense to use "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking"? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: The problem with using this as a close reason is that users who close questions for this reason re-interpret the words "minimal understanding" to mean "minimal effort," and that's not the same thing at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey IMHO, they are different but related and I'm not sure what the problem is with having them used for the same purpose. Often, "minimal understanding" is a direct reflection on the "minimal effort".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "minimal effort," except that it has never been a valid close reason on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm confused. Surely you aren't saying that there is nothing wrong with someone putting "minimal effort" into a solution before posting?

Comment: "Minimal understanding" has mostly to do with the OP having disclosed their relative level of expertise and demonstrated in their question that they would understand the answers that we give him.  "Demonstration of effort" has never been a requirement for asking a question on Stack Overflow.  This fundamental misunderstanding is what got the close reason removed in the first place.

Comment: Hmmm...I do see your point there but is a bit of a grey area on what the actually meaning of "minimal understanding" would be. We'll call it a draw

Comment: Whatever it means, it doesn't mean "minimal effort," although I do understand how it came to be interpreted that way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if "minimal effort" was never a requirement for asking a question on SO, then that would mean regurgitated homework and `icanhascodez` questions would overrun the site.  I'm pretty sure we discourage answering those?

Comment: Also I think part of the "problem" is that `icanhascodez` questions are intended to be downvoted rather than closed.  At least, that's the understanding I currently have, which might still be wrong...  either way, I'm not sure how many people understand it.  See my comment at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason#comment732115_215546 and Shog9's response.  This doesn't help for bad questions that receive (possibly also bad) answers though, IIUC.

Answer (score 1):

This now falls under Off Topic:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more
>   detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

The requirement of a minimal example requires a minimal understanding of the question and/or answer.