# I'm having some [difficulty] discerning what we could use this tag for

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [difficulty](/questions/tagged/difficulty) has 13 questions, no wiki or excerpt, and could be used for a *lot* of things:  Having difficulty deleting crap posts, burning tags, making waffles, etc. etc. etc.  There are a few posts where it looks applicable, such as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions) one, but overall it seems a bit ambiguous to be a good meta tag.

Thoughts?  Do y'all have any reasons for keeping it?

Comment: I agree, to put a halt to the vague usage - since you have the privilege (loaded word) might I suggest that you add a wiki thingy yourself and let the extant process proceed rather than posting a question here? Can you suggest a viable alternative which might have fitted the original intention as per your [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions)??

Comment: @ARogueAnt. 1) yep, I'll find an alt, 2) I wouldn't have posted this question if I had thought of a wiki.  What would it look like?  "For questions about difficulty at Stack Exchange"?  That's not concise enough.

Answer (score 13):

I see that we also have an [easy-questions](/questions/tagged/easy-questions) tag. Let's merge both of these tags into a [question-difficulty](/questions/tagged/question-difficulty) tag. This would cover things like how to find questions at a desired level of difficulty or what to do with questions that are perceived as too easy or too hard to answer.

Meta posts that are about some other kind of difficulty (e.g. behavior of "difficult" users, overly arcane rules and procedures, etc.), should receive a more appropriate tag in the applicable domain.

Comment: A good idea... the [tag:behavior] tag can be used for difficult users, as can the diamonds.

Comment: There are also posts about simple answers under the difficulty tag. Perhaps we should the more general [post-dificulty] instead? cc @Ollie

Comment: I've merged the two tags into question difficulty